# node version always is back , after closing terminal

Tags: node.js, terminal

I installed node 10.13 and am using mac 10.14.6.

However, after closing terminal, the version of the node is changed to 10.0.

I would appreciate it if you would tell me how to stick the node version.

```
$sudo n 10.13
$export PATH=$HOME/.nodebrew/current/bin:$PATH
```

Comment: Has your problem resolved?

Answer (score 3):

`nvm` (Node Version Manager) does its job by changing the PATH variable, so you need to make sure you aren't somehow changing your PATH to something else after sourcing the nvm.sh script.

Use the command in the terminal

```
nvm alias default v10.13
```

For more detail about the `nvm` , you can check the [link](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm)

In case, if you got error as `nvm not found` then you need to install that

To install nvm, use the install script cURL.

```
curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvm-sh/nvm/v0.34.0/install.sh | bash
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the path to `nodebrew` to your bash profile file. For example:

```
echo 'export PATH=$PATH:$HOME/.nodebrew/current/bin' >> ~/.bashrc
```

After this, you need to either reopen the terminal or run:

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

If you are using `zsh`, you will have to change `.zshrc` instead.

But as @Deep Kakkar mentioned, I also recommend using [`nvm`](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm) to manage different versions of node.